# Pl/SQL - Extract text and combine if duplicates

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Oracle 10g

My requirements are to:

1. Select each department
2. Select each individual item per department (each item get's its own row, but combine if duplicates)
3. Select each color per distinct department AND item (if duplicate, select the lowest number)
4. Select each user per distinct department AND item (aggregate if multiple)

DB data

```
Department    Item_List                  Color       User
Research      Item 1                    1. Blue      John
Research      Item 1;Item 2             2. Blue      Mike
Research      Item 1;Item 2; Item 3     1. Red       Steve
Research      Item 2                    1. Purple    John
Research      Item 1;Item 4             2. Red       Bill
Ops           Item 1;Item 2             3. Silver    John
Ops           Item 1;Item 3             3. Silver    Mike
Ops           Item 4                    4. Yellow    Mark
```

Expected Results

```
Department    Item_List         Color         User
Research        Item 1         1. Blue       John, Mike
Research        Item 2         1. Blue       Mike
Research        Item 1         1. Red        Steve, Bill
Research        Item 2         1. Red        Steve
Research        Item 3         1. Red        Steve
Research        Item 2         1. Purple     John
Research        Item 4         1. Red        Bill
Ops             Item 1         3. Silver     John, Mike
Ops             Item 2         3. Silver     John
Ops             Item 3         3 Silver      Mike
Ops             Item 4         4. Yellow     Mark
```

I am using the following SQL, but it is not working:

```
with data as 
(
select
DEPARTMENT, 
ITEM_LIST,
(length(ITEM_LIST)-length(replace(ITEM_LIST,';','')))+1 cnt,
MIN(Color) as Color,
wm_concat(USER) as USER
from DataBase_Table
Group by 
DEPARTMENT, 
ITEM_LIST
)
select 
DEPARTMENT
ITEM_LIST,
Color,
User
from
(
select distinct 
DEPARTMENT,
ltrim(regexp_substr(ITEM_LIST,'[^;]+',1,level)) ITEM_LIST, 
Color,
level,
User
from data
connect by level <= cnt
order by DEPARTMENT
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
   t1 as (
      select 
         department, 
         trim(regexp_substr(item_list, '[^;]+', 1, occ)) as item,
         to_number(regexp_substr(color, '^\d+')) as color_no, 
         regexp_replace(color, '^\d+(.*)$', '\1') as color_name, 
         user_
      from 
         (
            select level as occ from dual 
            connect by level <= (select max(length(item_list)) from source)
         ), 
         source
      where regexp_substr(item_list, '[^;]+', 1, occ) is not null
   )
select 
   department, 
   item,
   color, 
   listagg(user_, ',') within group (order by user_)
from
   (
      select 
         min(color_no)||color_name as color, 
         color_name
      from t1
      group by color_name
   ) 
   natural join t1 
group by 
   department, 
   item,
   color
order by 1 desc, 2, 3
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fa33/28)

In Oracle 10 you should use
`wm_concat(distinct user_)`
instead of
`listagg(user_, ',') within group (order by user_)`